# How to delete content between prefix and suffix

Tags: text-processing

I want to delete contents( multiple lines)  between my prefix and suffix only. My prefix and suffix should not be deleted.

I tried this but it removed my prefix and suffix:

```
sed -i "/prefix =/,/suffix =/d" myfile.txt
```

**Content:**

```
prefix = Content that i want to delete.
That includes multiple lines as
well as ASCII characters.
suffix = ,
```

**Output:**

```
prefix = 
suffix = ,
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is via awk and using `=` as field separator:

```
$ awk -F'=' 'BEGIN{OFS="=";};/^prefix/{$2=""; print; noprint=1};/^suffix/{noprint=0;print};noprint{next;};' input.txt
prefix =
suffix = ,
```

If there's other content before and after suffix that we want to get, same approach can be used with slight modification

```
$ awk -F'=' '/^prefix/{$2=""; printf "%s%s\n",$1,FS; noprint=1};/^suffix/||!noprint{noprint=0;print};noprint{next;};' input.txt
things beforeprefix
prefix =
suffix = ,
things after suffix
```

This, of course, can be shortened:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="=";};/^prefix/{p=1;$2="";print};/^suffix/{p=0};!p' input.txt
things beforeprefix
prefix =
suffix = ,
things after suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and worked fine

```
sed -n '/prefix/,/suffix/p' file.txt| awk '/prefix/||/suffix/{print $0}'| sed '/prefix = /s/=.*/=/g' >file_tmp.txt && mv file_tmp.txt file.txt
```

output

```
prefix =
suffix = ,
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit lines in a file, you could send commands to `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' '/^prefix =/+1,/^suffix =/-1d' '1,$s/^prefix = .*/prefix =/' 'wq' |ed -s myfile.txt
```

This sends three newline-separated commands to `ed` (who we instruct to startup and work silently on myfile.txt with the `-s` option):

- `/^prefix =/+1,/^suffix =/-1d` -- delete lines in the range of: "one after the line that matches `prefix =` at the beginning of the line" to "one before the line that matches `suffix =` at the beginning of the line"
- `1,$s/^prefix = .*/prefix =/` -- search and replace: in every line of the file, for the pattern `prefix =` followed by anything (or nothing) at the beginning of the line, replace it with just the text `prefix =`
- `wq` -- `w`rite the file back to disk and `q`uit `ed`

This makes some assumptions about your file and the translations you want:

- there is at least one line between the `prefix` and the suffix`
- you want every `prefix =` stripped of trailing text
- there's only one "stanza" of `prefix` and `suffix` to be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your requirements:

```
$ sed -ne '
   /^\(prefix =\).*/,/^\(suffix =.*\)/!p
   s//\1/p
' myfile.txt
```